# Batch File to Delete Files in a Folder

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I understand that there are tons of questions on this site regarding the creation of a batch file that goes through the file in a specified folder and deletes them if it satisfies the condition stated.

However, I would like to tweak that a little bit. In my batch file, I would like to look at a folder, say C:\Dev and get all the files that are within the same month. After getting all those files, I want to sort through all the dates and delete everything except for the latest one. So if I have 5 files for January on that folder with dates January 1, 12, 20, 27, and 30, I would only keep the file dated January 30th and delete all the others.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file that keeps the 7 latest files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367746/batch-file-that-keeps-the-7-latest-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: Then look at one of the other answers, like the one I've linked, and make an effort to "tweak it" yourself. You can't learn if you depend on everyone else to give you the code. :-) (The one I linked deletes all but the "latest 7", and it should be pretty easy to figure out how to modify it to "latest 1".) There are dozens of other similar questions here; I found that one by simply looking through the list of **Related** posts to the right of your question. =====>>>>>

Comment: ohhhh. i'm sorry! i didn't see this one! but thanks. yeah, looks pretty easy to tweak it. just have to figure out how to sort the files by month and do the deletion from there! thanks a lot! appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

< lang-dos -->

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "pfname="
PUSHD "%targetdir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /o:d "*" ') DO (
  SET "fname=%%a"
  SET "fdate=%%~ta"
  CALL :process
)
POPD

GOTO :EOF
:process
:: reformat date - this depends on yout local date-format.
:: YY(YY)MM required - my format is dd/mm/yyyy
SET fdate=%fdate:~6,4%%fdate:~3,2%
IF NOT DEFINED pfname GOTO nodel
IF %fdate%==%pfdate% ECHO DEL "%targetdir%\%pfname%"
:nodel
SET pfdate=%fdate%
SET "pfname=%fname%"
GOTO :eof
```

This should work for you. The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

First, the target directory is set up and `pfname` is cleared.

The `PUSHD` changes the `current directory` until the `POPD` is executed

the `dir` command outputs filenames only (`/b`), no directory names (`/a-d`) in date-order (`/o:d`). Each line sets `fname` to the filename and `fdate` to the filedate.

within `:process`, the date-string is manipulated. I don't know which format you use, but the basic formula is `%variable:~startposition,length%` where startposition starts at 0=first character. The idea is to have `fdate` in the format `yyyymm`

if `pfname` (previos filename) is not set, this is the first file found, so we don't delete that.

For every other file, if the filedate is the same as the previous filedate, then delete the previous filename.

The current filename/date is then recorded as the previous version.

Done!

Comment: Wow! This works like a charm!!! Thanks so much! Also big thanks for taking time to explain it! I use a different date format and your explanation saves me a lot of time and headache!!! Thanks so much!!!!!