# Keep newest file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I have read the [answer to "Batch File to Delete Files in a Folder" proposed by @Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21197928/4370109) and having tried the code but could not comment or ask additional questions, so I do apologize if I'm breaking some rules here.

Let me say up front that I may misunderstood how this is supposed to work.

First I made sure all files in the directory I wanted to clean up had the same date . 
I then replaced the c:\sourcedir with the name of said directory and ran the cmd file.

I expected it to produce an empty string, but got the full filelist.

Regardless of the fact that I may have missed something, this could turn out to be quite unfortunate.

I'm not very good at DOS/CMD stuff, so I was wondering if @Magoo might clarify this issue.

Comment: Try pasting the above into a comment in the correct thread now.  Delete this question if it works.

Comment: Can't do it - It seems silly but one has to have at least 50 reputation to comment, although for some reason I can do in my own thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you need, but can be used as a skeleton to start

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    pushd "c:\where\the\filesAre" && (
        for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /tw /o-d *') do echo del "%%a"
        popd
    )
```

First, the active directory is changed to the adecuated folder (change to your needs). Then a `for` command is used to execute a `dir` command and process its output. For each line in the `dir` output, the code after the `do` clause is executed, with the content of the line stored in the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`

The `dir` command will list the files in bare format (`/b` only file names), excluding directories (`/a-d`), in descending last write date order (`/tw /o-d`). So, the newest file is the first in the list (the output of the dir command) that the `for` command will process.

As we are asking `for` to skip one line (`skip=1`), this first file will be ignored. For the rest of the lines/files a del command is executed.

`del` operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command to delete the files.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure extensions to process
    set "_ext.00=al*.txt"
    set "_ext.01=cm*.txt"

    rem Change to the desired folder
    pushd "c:\where\the\filesAre" || goto :eof

    rem For each pattern in the list
    rem     For each file matching the pattern (except the newest)
    rem         Delete the file
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%x in ('
        set _ext.
    ') do for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /b /a-d /tw /o-d "%%~y" 2^>nul
    ') do echo del "%%a"

    popd
```

Define an "array" with the list of file patterns to process. For each of the patterns (retrieved with a `set` command inside the outter `for /f`) iterate over the files matching that pattern (the inner `for`), skipping the first/newest and removing the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'm not sure why, but this code does nothing on my machine except list all files bar one - that is the cmd file being executed. What I need is to keep the latest file for a given pattern as in AL*.TXT, CM*.TXT and so on, and delete the rest.

Comment: @webhiker, change the `*` into `al*.txt` and test

Comment: Now I'm getting only txt files, and it sort of works - but only if there is more than one file of it's kind. If there is only one, it will get deleted as well - and that just won't do. Also, it would be nice if one could pass the filemask as parameter.

Comment: Works like a charm - you are a prince! Is there a limit to the number of elements one can enter into the list? I'm up to ten by now and it works just fine - although I have not quite gotten around to removing the echo just yet :-)

Comment: @webhiker, the limit is the memory available in the environment block. From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `*Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP*:  The maximum size of the environment block for the process is 32,767 characters. Starting with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, there is no technical limitation on the size of the environment block.`